# Trying to change part of a class Java

Tags: java

I am trying to change part of a class (Character) so I can change the end as .isDigit for example.  Like I could change type tester to whaterver I want but I have no idea how I could do that.

```
 public static boolean testText (String password, int length,typeTester) {
    boolean test = false;
    for (int count = 0; count <= (length-1); count++){
      char resultConverted = password.charAt(count);
      if (Character.typeTest(resultConverted))
        test = true;
    }
    return test; 

  }
```

edit:
so there is now way to do better then just do something like this to analyse a word:

```
  public static boolean testUpperCase (String password, int length) {
    boolean upperCase = false;
    for (int count = 0; count <= (length-1); count++){
      char resultConverted = password.charAt(count);
      if (Character.isUpperCase(resultConverted))
        upperCase = true;
    }

    return upperCase;
  }
  public static boolean testLowerCase (String word, int length) {
    boolean lowerCase = false;
    for (int count = 0; count <= (length-1); count++){
      char resultConverted = word.charAt(count);
      if (Character.isLowerCase(resultConverted))
        lowerCase = true;
    }
    return lowerCase;

  }
```

It's just a question do find a more elegant alternative to what I have done so far.

Comment: You want to change the code of the `Character` wrapper class in the JDK?

Comment: You cannot add or modify methods of a class without extending it and `Character` is a `final` class so it cannot be extended. In short,you will have to create a method using methods in `Character` class to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: The `Character` class is `final` so you cannot add anything to it.  You can define your own `bool isFancyDancy(char)` method outside that class, however.  If you want to add something to your question, please use the “edit” function instead of posting a comment.

Comment: Why do you pass both a `word` and a `length` as parameters ? Java `String`s carry their length and you can get that via the `String.length()` method.

Comment: @still_learning: please make that an answer; it's not readable as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more elegant variant of `testUpperCase`:

```
boolean testUpperCase(String password) {
  for(char c : password.toCharArray()) {
    if(Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Re recursion in this situation: No. Just no. This is like using recursion for the Fibonacci sequence. (Person 1: Let's turn a `O(n)` operation into a `O(2^n)` operation! Person 2: Why didn't I think of that?).

Comment: @k_g If you read my answer, it clearly states that the recursive solution is inefficient. It just came to my mind when I thought about alternatives. However, I removed that (not recommended!) approach to avoid confusion.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. My confusion was due to the fact that there do exist people who try to use recursion for _everything_ because they can.

Answer (score 0):

If the String is not equal to the String converted to lowercase means that there should be some uppercase characters.

```
/* Test if there are any uppercase character in the string */
boolean testUpperCase(String password) {
    return !password.equals(password.toLowerCase());
}
```

And the same to test if the String has lowercase characters:

```
/* Test if there are any lowercase character in the string */
boolean testLowerCase(String password) {
    return !password.equals(password.toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: To find out whether the string contains upper case characters, you actually have to use `toLowerCase()` and vice versa.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to implement the methods in the question using ´toLowerCase()´ and ´toUpperCase()´.